# Check if cell contains one of many things, and return the thing

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, error-handling, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula to check if a string matches any of the substrings in an array, returning `true` or `false`.

When checking if the string `The number two` contains `one`, `two` or `three`, I'd like the formula to return `two` instead of `TRUE`. Is this possible in Google Sheets?

Here's the formula I'm using that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(things,A1)))>0
```

However, I'd like to see a string from the `things` array instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "one|two|three"), FALSE)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "one|two|three"), FALSE))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Can this also be used with a range? `=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, myrange), FALSE)` ?

Comment: sure: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "one|two|three"), FALSE))`